# How to reconstruct (changed) sys.argv from argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have an argparse that after parsing does preprocessing, changes and removes things etc.
Then it wraps a main that is used to get `sys.argv`.
Is there a preferred way to reconstruct a new `sys.argv` with the adapted fields?

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
args.new = args.old + "new"
main(args.get_sys_argv())
```

Comment: As the duplicates show there's no ONE way of recreating the `argv` given a resulting `args`.  But if you have `sys.argv` available, and the modified values are `flagged/optionals` arguments, you could just add them on, e.g. `argv += ['--new', args.old+'new']`,  On parsing the second '--new' will overwrite the value set by the first.  Tweaking the `positionals` in the existing `argv` will be harder.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I have found is a bit manual:

```
def to_sys_argv(self):
  argv = __name__ # reconstruct the current file as the calling one see *1*
  argv += " "
  argv += " ".join(f"--{k} {v}" for k, v in vars(self.args).items())

# one liner __name__ + " " + " ".join(f"--{k} {v}" for k, v in vars(self.args).items())
```

*1*: when reconstructing the calling name, it a bit depends on your goal.
If you have another argparse in main() it doesn't matter. Otherwise, you might want sys.argv[0] if intact or the main filename.

Comment: But..... `argv` is expected to be a list, not a string...

Answer (score 0):

```
   import sys
import argparse

# define the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example')
parser.add_argument('--old', type=str, help='Old argument')

# parse the arguments and do preprocessing
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
args.new = args.old + "new"

# create a new list of modified arguments
new_args = []
for key, value in vars(args).items():
    if value:
        new_args.extend(['--' + key, value])

# create a new sys.argv list with the modified arguments
new_argv = [sys.argv[0]] + new_args + unknown

# call the main function with the new sys.argv list
main(new_argv)
```

This code iterates over the args namespace using the vars() function, and constructs a list of strings representing the modified arguments. The if value: check ensures that only non-empty values are included in the list.

Then, the code constructs a new sys.argv list by concatenating the modified argument list with the unknown arguments.

Comment: But here you did not use all the changes done to args. just made them manually in the "if".